# AIR debug compile error ANE

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am trying to debug my air app but get the error:

```
Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.

invalid profile specified 'Application does not support current profile'

Launch command details:  "/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/sdks/4.6.0 AIR 3.5/bin/adl" -runtime "/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/sdks/4.6.0 AIR 3.5/runtimes/air/mac" -profile extendedMobileDevice -screensize 768x1004:768x1024 -XscreenDPI 132 -XversionPlatform IOS -extdir "/Users/kerepuki/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/.metadata/.plugins/com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.ui/ANEFiles/AppName/macosx/" "/Volumes/Mobile Apps/AppName/Application/Final/bin-debug/AppName-app.xml" "/Volumes/Mobile Apps/AppName/Application/Final/bin-debug"
```

I don't think it is related to an ANE I am trying to add as I have tested the ANE in a blank project and it works fine.

If I package the app and install on iPad it works fine. I am using AIR 3.5 in Flash Builder and not sure how to debug this error message.

My application file starts with:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.5">
```

Answer (score 2):

Had to remove the supported profile node from the application description file.